# Fetch old reactions to an old message

Tags: discord.js

I've written a discord.js bot with version 12.0.2 and some features have been running for a while but are now disfunctionning and it seems to be related to empty cache, but I can't manage to figure out how to solve it.

Here is the scenario :

> I have my bot weekly posting a message on a server and guild members have a week to react to this message. At the end of the week, I want to analyze the reactions to the bot to decide what to do (I can't have the bot running 24/7 to await for reactions).

Here is my problem :

> Once I've fetched this specific message, what I did until now was `msg.reactions.resolve('✅').users.fetch().then(somestuff)`, but since a few weeks it stopped functionning and now throws `(node:2336) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of null`.

I've been through some debugging steps and found out that `msg.reactions.cache` is empty, hence here I think the problem is, but I cannot find how to fill it.
Here is what `msg.reactions` contains:

```
ReactionManager {
  cacheType: [Function: Collection],
  cache: Collection [Map] {},
  message: Message {
    details_about_the_message_that_confirm_it_is_the_desired_one_that_have_been_reacted_to
  }
}
```

Would anybody have ideas about how to solve this please ? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you !

Comment: Have you tried debugging what's returned from the Discord API? I'm assuming you're fetching the message (like `channel.messages.fetch(id)`), so you could see what `data.reactions` is in [this line](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/12.2.0/src/structures/Message.js#L131).

Comment: @cherryblossom Hi there, sorry for the long time between your answer and mine! I've edited my question to add details about `data.reactions`

Comment: I realised I was mistaken about resolving an emoji into a reaction; that should still work because Discord.js uses the emoji name (the actual Unicode emoji) or the ID for custom emojis. I’ve deleted my incorrect answer, sorry about that.

Comment: There's no harm, don't worry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found a solution, or maybe I'd better call it a workaround, hence I'm sharing it here to close this post.

First of all, I have to say that `msg.reactions.resolve('✅').users.fetch().then(somestuff)` does its work and is not part of the problem, as the problem was lying in the message fetching process. Fetching a bunch of messages or fetching a specific one (*i.e.* by ID) leads to different results.

Fetching a specific message by ID let you access the `ReactionManager`'s cache, while fetching several messages seems not to populate the cache.

Comment: You just saved my life, I was doing the same exact thing but with `fetch()` instead of `resolve([emoji])`. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure, happy to ear it helped someone ! :)